# Custom Installer for Custom Package

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation, custom-module

I got a custom package which contains a component and few modules and few plugins.  The installation of this package takes about 2 to 3 minutes and some time it crosses the PHP maximum execution time and result in a partial installation.

I see few extensions using their own installer (Kunena, Jomsocial etc...) I explored some of their code and I understand that they bypass the Joomla core installer and write their own file transfers, database amendments etc... using AJAX calls (to avoid hitting the maximum execution time)

I was thinking why cant I do a similar custom script for my package.  Before writing something just thought of checking the below with you.

1. Am I stepping in the correct direction?
2. Are there any script already exists?
3. Will joomla support these type of installations in future release?